# How to retrieve the value of a field in the master part of a master detail relationship from the detail part in the entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a master Detail relationship in my entity model (to make it easy think of the classic Northwind Orders-OrderDetails)  The end user will enter the details for the master part in a grid and then move down to a lower grid to enter the 'related' details.

From within the entity Model itself I would like to be able to retrieve the equivalent of the 'CustomerId' value from the Orders Table each time that I create a new OrderDetail record related to that order and use it to retrieve some specific information that needs to be in each detail record.

Is there an easy way to do this in the entity model itself.  I'll be doing this in vb but I can just about read C#.

Additional Info for clarification:

Jeric raised an interesting point in his answer, for which I thank him, that this suggests that the table might not be properly normalised.  Under any normal circumstances I would agree, but here I am forced by constraints outside of my control.  Tis is for an application that records landings of fish by commercial fishermen.  Each landing may comprise several different species of fish and all landing details must by law be reported to government bodies who in turn pass the information on to scientists who use it to calculate fish stocks and hence quota limits for catches.

To this end exactly where the fish was caught is of importance so each line detail (a landing detail line) must record the area and zone where the item was caught.  For most small boats this information will almost always be the same (but larger boats that go to sea for months can catch fish in several areas and zones(hence the requirement)).

To try and make this easier for the end user of the application I felt that it would make sense to record details of a default area and zone in the vessel record (the equivalent of the Northwind customer).  Within the landing header table (the Northwind Order) I have a reference to the vesselId.  so as landing detail lines are entered I would like to refer back to the landing header  and retrieve the vessel ID to then use that as a parameter in functions to retrieve the default area and zone associated with that vessel.

As I'm using the entity Framework to do this I do not yet know what the final ID of the landing will be (it hasn't yet been committed, the beauty of the entity framework being that it makes this sort of data entry easy) so I'm trying to get the vessel id from the landing header that has yet to have an 'official' id created for it.

I hope that makes more sense for a question that would in most cases (myself included) prompt one to think that this is a database normalisation issue.

What I'm trying to do is find a way in one of the On PropertyChanging events of the landing detail entity to retrieve the vesselId of its associated landing header entity which as yet is still to be committed to the database.  It's in the clientcache but not yet in the database.

Many Thanks

Comment: Make "CustomerId" a member of your "Order" class.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correct, you're saying that there are some properties in your OrderDetail entity that are populated based on your Customer entity. I find this strange because you should be able to query for any Customer details from the OrderDetail entity by traversing the link from OrderDetail to Order to Customer. There should be no need for you to persist a Customer property (e.g. Gender) under the OrderDetail table. You might want to consider trying to better normalize your schema.

In any case, say you have these entities:

```
public class Customer {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;} //<-- I'm also assuming you have a 1 Customer to Many Order relationship
}


public class Order {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
    public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;} //<-- assumes a Customer Entity also exists
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;} //<-- I'm also assuming you have a 1 Order to Many Order Detail relationship
}

public class OrderDetail {
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     [Required]
     public int OrderId {get; set;} //<-- each Order Detail *must* be linked to an order
     public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
     public string CustomerGender {get; set;} //<-- property that gets populated based on the customer that is related to the parent Order of this detail
     //other properties
 }
```

When you construct your OrderDetail instance, you should know what order it is linked to, but not necessarily the Customer as can be seen in this case:

```
var orderDetail = new OrderDetail {OrderId = 1};
```

In your insert method, you want to make sure you get the Customer detail and populate the relevant field in the orderDetail, prior to inserting. Since you know the OrderId, you can use LINQ to query for the relevant Customer detail. In this example we want to get Customer.Gender and assign it to OrderDetail.CustomerGender. You can probably write this out in one statement but I will break it down for easier readability.

```
//step 1, get the Customer object based on the OrderId
var cust = context.Set<Order>().Include(o => o.Customer)
                  .Where(o => o.Id == orderDetail.OrderId)
                  .Select(o => o.Customer).SingleOrDefault();

//step 2, assign the Customer object property to the OrderDetail instance
orderDetail.CustomerGender = customer.Gender;

//step 3, persist the orderDetail entity
context.Set<OrderDetail>().Add(orderDetail);
context.SaveChanges();
```